# I can't find the option to use fixed naming and single page assemblies in Visual Studio 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

I can't find the option to use fixed naming and single page assemblies in Visual Studio 10. I have a Web application and when I go to publish it, I do not see the option to use fixed naming and single page assemblies like I did with VS2008.  Does anyone know where to specify that option in VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

This option is only available for certain deployment options:

http://mauricio.hernaski.com.br/blog/difference-between-web-site-and-web-application-in-asp.net-4/english